# Nativescript 8.5 android and ios app size is > 200mb. is it ok?

Tags: migration, nativescript, size, nativescript-vue

After switching from ns 7 to ns 8.5, the size of the application has grown by 2 times, given that the application code has not changed at all. This is fine? And if not, what can you please tell me how to reduce the size of the application

```
"dependencies": {
"@finanzritter/nativescript-pdf-view": "^3.0.3",
"@nativescript-community/ui-pulltorefresh": "^2.5.3",
"@nativescript/appversion": "^2.0.0",
"@nativescript/background-http": "6.0.0",
"@nativescript/camera": "^5.0.12",
"@nativescript/core": "8.5.0",
"@nativescript/email": "^2.0.5",
"@nativescript/firebase-core": "^3.0.0",
"@nativescript/firebase-firestore": "^3.1.0",
"@nativescript/firebase-messaging": "^3.0.0",
"@nativescript/local-notifications": "^6.0.0",
"@nativescript/localize": "^5.0.4",
"@nativescript/theme": "^2.3.3",
"@nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus": "4.2.0",
"@nstudio/nativescript-carousel": "^8.0.3",
"@nstudio/nativescript-pulltorefresh": "^3.0.2",
"@triniwiz/nativescript-socketio": "^5.0.1",
"@triniwiz/nativescript-toasty": "^4.1.3",
"axios": "^0.20.0",
"nativescript-advanced-webview": "^7.0.0",
"nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.5.1",
"nativescript-permissions": "^1.3.12",
"nativescript-phone": "^2.0.0",
"nativescript-share-file": "^1.0.6",
"nativescript-toasty": "^3.0.0-alpha.2",
"nativescript-trace-sentry": "^1.0.0",
"nativescript-vue": "~2.9.3",
"nativescript-websockets": "^1.5.6",
"nativescript-webview-interface": "^1.4.3",
"util": "^0.12.5",
"v-mask": "^2.3.0",
"vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
"vuex": "^3.5.1"
```

},

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@nativescript/android": "8.5.0",
    "@nativescript/ios": "8.5.0",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.12",
    "nativescript": "~8.5.3",
    "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "~2.9.3",
    "typescript": "~4.4.0"
  }
```

in webpack config i use

```
config.resolve.alias.set('os', false)
        config.resolve.alias.set('tty', false)
        config.resolve.alias.set('zlib', false)
        config.resolve.alias.set('https', false)
        config.resolve.alias.set('http', false)
        config.resolve.alias.set('url', false)
        config.resolve.alias.set('stream', false)
        config.resolve.alias.set('assert', false)
        config.resolve.alias.set('util', 'util')
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to clean the cache of NPM? you can do it by using this command:

```
npm cache clean
```